# Combine preventdefault with passing data object to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that dynamically adds an onclick event to a collection of hyperlinks:

```
function DisplayContent(event) {        
     alert("Showing " + event.data.classToShow);
}

$(document).ready(function () {     
    $(".modules ul li a").each(function () {
        // alert($(this).data("classname-to-show")); // alerts 'tileHelloWorld' correctly
        $(this).on("click", { classToShow: $(this).data("classname-to-show") }, DisplayContent);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="modules">
     <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-classname-to-show="tileHelloWorld">Hello</a>
        </li>
        <li>....</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This works fine, but I'd also like to use `event.preventDefault` to stop the default event of the hyperlink after it is clicked.  After searching, I see I can expand the code be something like `$(this).on("click", function (event) {`, but I can't figure out how to combine the two.

Can anyone help me utilise both please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any good reason for passing data to the event handler in this case, so just access the data-attribute inside the event handler instead, like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modules ul li a").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = $(this).data("classname-to-show");
        alert("Showing " + data);
    });
});
```

Or the way you're already doing it, you already have the event, so all you need is

```
function DisplayContent(event) {        
     event.preventDefault();
     alert("Showing " + event.data.classToShow);
}
```